# Removing the first word in each line in python

Tags: python-3.x

My Text file currently looks like this:

```
1 1.094141 -19.991062 -0.830169
2 0.506693 -19.613609 -2.876364
3 -0.355470 -18.932575 -4.884786
4 -0.354663 -27.707542 -21.295307
5 1.008405 -18.191206 -4.542386
6 2.663746 -19.178164 -5.195459
10 0.245458 -17.983212 -2.999652
11 1.411953 -20.360981 -4.684113
```

I need a program to remove the first character from each line to make it look like:

```
1.094141 -19.991062 -0.830169
0.506693 -19.613609 -2.876364
-0.355470 -18.932575 -4.884786
-0.354663 -27.707542 -21.295307
1.008405 -18.191206 -4.542386
2.663746 -19.178164 -5.195459
0.245458 -17.983212 -2.999652
1.411953 -20.360981 -4.684113
```

How do I do this in Python? I have more than 200 files with a similar data and I need to delete the first character. Please help me with the code. Thank you! :)

Well, I am also trying to do other things but I want to fix the logic in this code of mine.

```
import numpy as np

with open('test2.txt') as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()

with open('test2.txt') as infile:

    with open('Output.txt', 'a') as outfile:
        outfile.write('# vtk Datafile Version 3.0 \n')
        outfile.write('Unstructured Grid.. \n')
        outfile.write('ASCII\n')

        copy = False
        for line in infile:

            if line.strip() == "651734":
                copy = True
            elif line.strip() == "$EndNodes":
                copy = False
            elif line.strip() == "3089987":
                copy = True
            elif copy:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Have you tried any code? Show us what you already have started so that we can answer your problem.

Comment: I am tried using line.strip() to read certain portions in a .txt file but I couldn't find a way to remove just the first word.

Comment: If it doesn't strictly need to be python, this simple shell one-liner also does the trick using the [cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) command: `cut -d ' ' -f 2- test2.txt > Output.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lines will split the lines you're fed to the `lines` variable on line 4 of your code, and remove the word that comes before the first space.

```
for line, i  in enumerate(lines):
    lines[i] = line.split(" ", 1)[1]
```

Keep in mind that this will only work if your line always follows the layout you outlined above.

Read up on how to use split properly [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)
and, of course, study the python documents again carefully.

Having said that, it also looks like the second `with open(test2.txt)` is superfluous; you have stored the lines of that file in your `lines` variable on line 4 already, so right there you're just wasting space and memory.

You should probably sketch out your idea again, before you continue writing your program. Right now it's quite redundant and not very well thought through.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is almost correct but not exactly accurate. The code tries to use "line" as an iterator instead of "i."

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    lines[i] = line.split(" ", 1)[1]
```